# Why do we need action attribute in HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have recently learned about processing form in a webpage.
As far as I understand, the value in the form will be loaded into a superglobal array $_POST which can be accessed in any file.
Why do we need action attribute in HTML form to specify a destined file.

Comment: Because you dont normally want to process the form data from the same page that throws the form because among other things that can cause issues when the use presses F5

Comment: _accessed in any file_ Well accessed in the file with the form in it OR the file mentioned in the `action` attribute. Not just any file at any time

Comment: The action specifies a destination **URL**, not necessarily a file. These will often essentially refer to the same thing (until you start learning about URL rewriting), but the distinction is important. HTTP requests all need to point *somewhere*, and the action attribute tells the form where to submit the data. Note that the attribute is technically optional - by default a form will submit back to the current URL.

Comment: So how about the processing flow of PHP. PHP will process data in the file mentioned in the 'action' attribute and then turn back to the form, won't it ?
If that's the case. Can I say that 'action' attribute act as 'include'

Comment: What do you mean "turn back to the form"? The PHP file that renders the form and the one that processes the form are completely independent. The file in the action attribute can do whatever you like with the data submitted, and then return any kind of response to the browser - another form, a completely new page, redirect to a whole new site, etc. The second file doesn't run at all until the form is submitted.